# Why my web.config is scrambled in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-config

This morning, all the sudden my project complains lots of thing, I then found out because the whole web.config is scrambled to something I don't know.

Fortunately I had a backup, after restoring Rebuild got this:
  Error 3   Application Configuration file "Web.config" is invalid. '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 1.

Here is the first 2 lines of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

1> What is web.config scrambled unintentionally?
2> IE can display this restored web.config, why VS is complaining?

More info about my machine:
- Win 7 64-bit, running perfect w/ VS 2008/13 installed for a while.
- VS 2013 Community.

Answer (score 1):

The file may become corrupted and encoding was changed during saving.

Open the web.config file with Notepad++ (or any text editor) and make sure the encoding is set to UTF8.

[image: Notepad++ encoding options]

if not, save it and check if it solved your issue.

Hope it support your issue.

Comment: Have you find it useful?